# Help with summation question regarding exponents and coefficients

Tags: summation

I need help with this one problem:
    $$\sum_{i=1}^n (2i+ 2^i)$$

Okay...I worked out a solution and came to the answer of: $n^2 + n + 2^{n + 1}$

but I am told the answer is $n^2 + n + 2^{n + 1} - 2$.

How is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2i+2^i=\sum_{i=1}^n 2i+\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i=2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{(2)(2^{n}-1)}{2-1}=n^2+n+2^{n+1}-2$$

Comment: Thank you. Ahh geometric series.